# Display div if javascript is enabled. Must have !important

Tags: javascript, css

I have a featured slider on my homepage that I had rigged to be completely hidden if javascript is disabled. I had a script that would then display the featured slider if javascript was enabled.

```
    document.write('<style type="text/css">#JQuerySlider1Container{ display: block !important;}</style>');
```

Apparently that code is not valid according to W3C. (Though it worked so this is a total bummer).

I found an alternative piece of code that I like but I must have !important in order for the slider to be displayed.

```
document.getElementById('JQuerySlider1Container').style.display='block !important';
```

But it doesn't work with !important.
Does anybody have a simple solution for this problem?

Comment: Why would you use `document.write` to write something that's constant? Just write the style element directly. That's valid.

Comment: !important is not a valid syntax in inline style. Inline style is always "more important" of the rest

Comment: @chumkiu: I used to think that, but it's not true. A sufficiently specific `!important` rule applied via styles can take precedence over an inline style: [Example](http://jsbin.com/uwifas/1), [Source](http://jsbin.com/uwifas/1/edit) And `!important` *does* work in inline styles: [Example](http://jsbin.com/uwifas/3), [Source](http://jsbin.com/uwifas/3/edit)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder uops... I see now, you're right. i didn't know it. Thanks

Comment: The only reason I have the slider hidden is because that div leaves a big gaping hole on the homepage if javascript is disabled and I have another feature that looks very similar to the original slider in it's place.

Comment: But if I don't use !important, if doesn't show up PERIOD.

Comment: @chumkiu: Yeah, surprising, isn't it? But since `!important` *does* work in inline styles, you can always "win" with the inline. :-)

Comment: Do you have an example of how I could do that? My css terminology is kind of lacking.

Comment: @chumkiu take a look at this beautiful poster ;) http://www.standardista.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/specifishity.gif !important = NUKE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not good practice to add CSS using JS. You should keep HTML, JS and CSS all completely separated.

The way to show/hide things using JS is by default hide the objects you want to hide using CSS, e.g:

```
#JQuerySlider1Container {display:none;}
```

The in your JS, add a class to the body, using something like:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').addClass('has-js');
});
```

Then you can write specific CSS rules knowing that you have JS enabled, e.g:

```
.has-js #JQuerySlider1Container {display:block;}
```

Comment: This is the way to go. Depending on the complexity of your site, you might benefit from using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), which will deal with this for you as well as providing other useful `classes` to help style the page according to the browser's capabilities.